# Shapes in WPF canvas do not appear

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drawing

I have encounteres a very weird issue with drawing shapes on a canvas in WPF.

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="3">
            <Canvas Name="BottomCanvas" Margin="15" Background="Yellow">
                <Canvas Name="TransparentCanvas" Background="Transparent"
                        MouseDown="TransparentCanvas_MouseDown"
                        MouseUp="TransparentCanvas_MouseUp"
                        MouseMove="TransparentCanvas_MouseMove"
                       Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}},Path=ActualWidth}"
                        Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                        AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}},Path=ActualHeight}">
                </Canvas>
            </Canvas>

        </DockPanel>
```

Above there is my canvas defined.

Below there is a simple example of drawing an elipse; I have no idea why this has no effect.

```
                Ellipse myEllipse = new Ellipse();
                SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
                mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255, 0);
                myEllipse.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
                myEllipse.Width = myEllipse.Height = 100;
                Canvas.SetTop(myEllipse, 15);
                Canvas.SetLeft(myEllipse, 15); ;
                bottomCanvas.Children.Add(myEllipse);
```

Can anyone see what is wrong?

EDIT:
I'm sorry. As you can see in XAML canvas is named 'BottomCanvas' and in code I've used `bottomCanvas` which is a property added to a `MainWindow` I don't know what for. That was the deal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean the `Ellipse` is not visible? It's just because of the transparent fill of `SolidColorBrush`. The `Alpha` value of the `Color` should not be zero, which means invisible. If so, just change the `Alpha` value of the `Color`:

```
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0);
```

Comment: That's an observant notice. Thanks!

Comment: @wis.niowy Could you accept this answer so that others can quickly get the problem?